# Deleting array object in Meteor/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to delete an Object inside an array, I have tried both pull and unset in Meteor.update but the entire array is being deleted instead of just the individual object inside the array.

Code for what I've tried

```
Cars.update( 
    { _id: id},
    { $unset: { 'models': { '$.id': modelId  }  } })
```

And

```
Cars.update( 
{ _id: id},
{ $pull: { 'models': { 'id': modelId  }  } })
```

In both cases, the entire 'models' attribute was deleted instead of just an object from the array

Schema for Cars:

```
models : {
type: [Object],
optional: true
},

'models.$.id': {
type: String,
autoValue: function() {
    return Meteor.uuid()
},
optional: true
}
```

Essentially, the collections 'Cars' contains an array 'models' which is an array of objects (car models). Each car model object has an attribute id. I want to delete an individual car model from the models array using the attribute 'id' but my above attempts deleted the entire 'models' array instead of the individual object. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Before

```
{
"_id" : "XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-04T08:05:59.151Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-04T08:36:11.785Z"),
"models" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Mercedes",
        "id" : "9927cfe1-f5ae-4625-b6eb-87868793a229"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "BMW",
        "id" : "86f24e9d-dd08-4407-b350-63d9b25dc094"
    }
]
}
```

After

```
{
"_id" : "XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-04T08:05:59.151Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-04T09:38:56.470Z")
}
```

The parent object is XxbKz... and it contains an attribute models which is an array of objects (BMW,Mercedes). I want to delete the BMW object from the XxbKz parent object. I queried the parent object using its id (XxbKz...) and the BMW object using its id (86f2...) as well (code in original post). The result was that the entire models array got deleted (both BMW and Mercedes) instead of just BMW.

My Meteor call was

```
Meteor.call('deleteCar','XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq','86f24e9d-dd08-4407-b350- 
    63d9b25dc094') 

deleteCar(carId, modelId) {
check(carId, String)
check(modeld, String)
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    let car = Cars.update( {_id: carId},
      { $pull: { 'models': { 'id': modelId  }  } }
    )   
    console.log(car)
    return car
  }
}
```

}

The variables in the deleteCar function are carId(XxbK) and modelId(86f2) which are the first and second parameters from the deleteCar meteor call. From my understanding, just the BMW from the parent should have been deleted but for some reason this is not the case

Comment: The only correct one is of course the `$pull` because `$unset` does something else entirely. Care to show an actual document and the values you are sending which you expect to match? Note that `$pull` will remove "everything" which matches the condition supplied. So if you have multiple array elements matching the same condition, then removing "all" of them is expected. Show a document so we can see what you can possibly be doing wrong here.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2313887)

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry for all those deleted comments. I meant to go to the next line by pressing enter but it submitted my comment. I've added the pictures in the original post now

Comment: I believe the point there was to work out you open up the "text" view tab and copy the "text" instead of the image. I cannot copy an "image" into my own collection and run the statement myself now can I? I can do that with "text" however. That was the lesson you were meant to learn when you could not post images.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ahhh that makes sense! I've edited the original post again to match the guidelines

Comment: Much better. So which one are we "pulling"? The Merc or the BMW? So these would appear to be strings and are you certain you are also using a variable that matches the string type.

Comment: The BMW. My Meteor call was 
    Meteor.call('deleteCar','XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq','86f24e9d-dd08-4407-b350-63d9b25dc094') and then the deleteCar function is the Cars.update call in the original post. The variables in the deleteCar function are id(XxbK) and modelId(86f2) which are the first and second parameters from the deleteCar meteor call. From my understanding, just the BMW from the parent should have been deleted but for some reason this is not the case

Comment: Again, much better when you put these details "in the question itself" Leave the warbling in the comments to me as I'll sweep them up later. But your content and explanation belongs "in the question". Then you can also include the code for this `deleteCar` method you are calling so we can look at that too.

Comment: @NeilLunn I undertand, I have a good idea on how to base my future questions now. I've added the deleteCar function to the OP.

Comment: Okay, AFAIK `.update()` does not return the modified document. You seem to be expecting it to return the updated document, but it "should" only be returning a response indicating what has matched and updated. At least that's the standard API implementation. This should be removing the correct array item. Also it's just a single document update, so why do you really need to do the remote call? Again AFAIK `.update()` calls from the browser are fine just as long as they include the `_id` and are therefore not able to affect multiple documents.

Comment: @NeilLunn Im testing my Meteor methods and schema in the meteor shell terminal. .update() does return 0 or 1 but I'm checking for the result in studio3T so I can see exactly what is happening in the Collection. Studio3T is showing that the whole array is being deleted instead of the correct array item.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole array deleted"? What are you actually executing? I don't see the need for anything to be different, so simply `db.cars.update({ "_id": "XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq" },{ "$pull": { "models": { "id": "86f24e9d-dd08-4407-b350-63d9b25dc094" } } })` does exactly what is expected. If you think different, then show what you are actually doing and what the document looks like after you run the statement. "text" please.

Comment: @NeilLunn I added the result in the post. I tried out your db.cars.update() statement in studio3T and it worked exactly as it was supposed to. The only difference in my Meteor call from your call is that I call a Meteor method (deleteCar) that calls update() and it uses variables for the ids instead of directly inputting the ids as it does in yours. For some reason, the behavior of mine is completely different from yours when the only difference between our update() is variable input vs static input.

Answer (score 1):

This works to remove Mercedes from your example.

`db.cars.update({_id: 'XxbKzS6GHthxwnLFq'}, {$pull: {models: {id: '9927cfe1-f5ae-4625-b6eb-87868793a229'}}})`

Looks just like

```
 Cars.update( 
{ _id: id},
{ $pull: { 'models': { 'id': modelId  }  } })
```

I did run this from the mongo shell and not meteor. However I have used $pull from within Meteor no problem.

I have never used the return update, it may well be returning the original document before updating. I would add this instead.

```
Cars.update( {_id: carId},
      { $pull: { 'models': { 'id': modelId  }  } }
    )       
const car = Cars.findOne(carId)
console.log(car)
return car
```

Good luck and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your method worked on mongo shell but not meteor. However, I did manage to figure out the problem, there was a bug in the validation process of the schema framework I was using (SimpleSchema), the solution was to pass getAutoValues:false in the update() which made the pull work without a problem